Why does adding a capacitor in parallel with an avalanche diode reduce the noise amplitude?
I'm trying to make a simple avalanche noise random number generator.
This is my circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Without C1 the "avalanche rate" is approximately 560khz, and the noise Vpp is approximately 190mV, as measured with a 10x scope probe.
My reason for adding C1 is to reduce the output rate. My target is 20kHz. I could increase R1, but I would like a low output impedance so I can read this directly with an ADC (with a DC blocking capacitor.)
I expected that C1 would reduce the output rate, but not reduce the noise Vpp. In practice it did reduce the output rate to 63kHz, but it also reduced the Vpp dramatically, to 60mV.
Why is that? The model in my mind says the voltage rises to some random voltage and then an avalanche kicks off and the voltage drops below a threshold. Increasing the capacitance should just make this happen slower, but clearly that is not correct.
Edit:
Signal without cap:

Signal with cap (note timescale):

Notice that in the time domain this is not "noise". But rather a sawtooth signal with a random tooth height.
I'm not sure what determines the height distribution of the teeth. Apparently it does not work the way I thought it did.

That capacitor rolls off your high-frequency. So of course the amplitude will be attenuated at high-frequency. It's basicaaly shorting high-frequency spikes to ground.

Added info. Note that in the time domain, the signal is not simple noise.

The thing is, you can condition the signal a bunch of different ways prior to sampling. If the purpose is for generating random numbers, it is unclear why this so called rate is imperative.

I want to make sure I'm measuring the random part of the signal, and only that. The tooth height or length. The ramp rate for example is not random. If the frequency of the signal is too high, we won't know exactly what we're sampling. I want to read this sawtooth accurately. Hence the frequency needs to be limited.

You can just read an adc with nothing attached and you will get "random" numbers. This paradoxically makes things harder, because the system may appear to be working, while it's actually producing low quality entropy.

Background: https://betrusted.io/avalanche-noise

Keep in mind you don't have the complete circuit. The reason it is AC coupled, is so that you DO have only the ramp portion. The AC coupling removes the "non-random component" aka the DC bias. Any signal that is not part of the DC is the random signal.

Furthermore, the upstream circuit is being driven by a switching regulator which will add considerable random dynamics to the system which you do not have in your depicted circuit - you have a (nearly) constant current source.

The ramp rate is not random, it's a resistor charging capacitance. There is no switching regulator, it's driven by 4x 9V batteries. The avalanche noise is "perfectly" random (based on quantum physics). I want to measure that and only that as much as possible.

You can model low-current avalanche breakdown as the random initiation of an avalanche cascade.
When high electric field is present, and some free charges start crossing the depletion region (or are created randomly within it by thermal energy), they are accelerated until impact ionization occurs.  This frees more charges, and so on.  By the time ionization is complete and electrons and holes have crossed the junction, a much larger gulp of charge has been delivered, big enough to see easily in circuit.  When this charge settles through the junction and surrounding circuit, it causes a sudden drop in node voltage.  With the large-value resistor and not much else, this charge is mostly removed from the diode junction capacitance itself.  The avalanche process may be a single (once-across) cascade, or repeating continuously as long as voltage is high enough to sustain it; in this case, most likely it acts like an arc discharge, conducting continuously until the voltage falls below threshold.
A key insight is, as voltage goes up, the avalanche multiplication ratio increases.  At lower voltages in this region, the discharge may peter out quickly, delivering little charge, or simply pulling voltage below threshold quickly.  Likewise it's less likely to initiate a full discharge.  At high voltages, the discharge is more likely to pull voltage completely down.
Avalanche breakdown is a highly localized phenomenon.  If you had a transparent junction (like an avalanche photodiode) and infrared microscope (or actually, visible light is even emitted in this process, though the junction must be very close to the surface indeed for that light to escape), you could photograph this process in real time: it would look like tiny flashes of lightning across the chip.
With a capacitor in parallel, charging is slower, i.e. more time is spent only slightly above threshold; and the discharge removes charge from the junction and capacitor jointly, resulting in a smaller voltage change for given delivered charge.  The repeat rate rises, because charge per pulse is lower; we can deduce that the avalanche gain is lower.
The ramp is fixed by junction capacitance and pull-up current.  We see the slope is steeper in the first case than the second, in agreement with \$I = C \frac{dV}{dt}\$.
For reference, here's the DC-coupled view of an avalanche waveform, of a lightly-biased 2N3904:

From: 2N3904_Avalanche.jpg | Seven Transistor Labs, own work
The large downward spike on the left (also the oscilloscope trigger event) is peculiar to BJT avalanche in a certain operating regime (and the apparent undershoot below GND can be blamed on probe compensation... or I just didn't label it correctly and breakdown is actually 100V, heh), but the rough "grass" thereafter exhibits familiar statistics.  There are several waveforms overlapped in the photograph, I think, hence it doesn't seem to be a one-to-one function; but we can see how the multiplication proceeds until voltage drops below threshold, and how initiation occurs randomly when voltage is above threshold.
With AC coupling as in your circuit, that baseline isn't visible, and the peak and valley voltages distribute a little bit; but not evenly, so we still get some flavor for this.

Thanks I think that explains it.


I expected that C1 would reduce the output rate, but not reduce the noise Vpp. In practice it did reduce the output rate to 63kHz, but it also reduced the Vpp dramatically, to 60mV.
Why is that?

Avalanche breakdown is a stochastic (random) process that increases in probability as the "excess" voltage across the avalanche diode (voltage above a threshold) increases.
By placing a capacitor in parallel with the avalanche diode, you decrease the rate at which the voltage across the diode rises. As a result, more time is spent at lower excess voltages, and consequently the avalanche breakdown will occur (on average) at lower excess voltages.

The model in my mind says the voltage rises to some random voltage and then an avalanche kicks off and the voltage drops below a threshold. Increasing the capacitance should just make this happen slower, but clearly that is not correct.

The model you were using does not take into account the fact the avalanche kicks off at a random time with a probability that depends on the voltage above the threshold. Spending more time at lower voltages above the threshold increases the probability of avalanche events at lower voltages.

Thanks for the succinct explanation! That makes sense.

One way to look at it is to consider the impedance of the capacitor, given by X = 1/(2πfC). The frequency is f, and the capacitance is C.
At 20KHz, this gives an impedance of about 24K ohm. Much less than the 3.3M ohm of the resistor in series with it, that's supplying the current to the diode.
So C1 is essentially shorting out all your high frequency noise from the diode.

I don't think this is it. At least not in the time domain. You'll notice in the screenshots that it does not round off the signal, as you would expect with a low pass effect.

@Drew you are not seeing enough of the signal to see the low-pass filter effect because it avalanches. At such a small dt compared to the time-constant of the circuit, the ramps are virtually linear. Couple that with limited scope resolution, the the trace is linear. Although hard to tell (different time scales), the rise time seems faster with the non-capacitor set up (as expected).

I will be measuring the actual waveform at similar timescale to what I'm seeing in the scope, so if the effect is not visible it's not really relevant. There is a visible issue, which is that the height of the sawteeth is reduced.

@Drew The reduced sawtooth isn't an issue - it's a side-effect of a Parelle shunt capacitor. This effect is inherent to all RC circuits of this kind and the attenuation rolls off the frequency at 6dB/oct (in first-order). Notice in the circuit from the link you posted that the pre-noise signal is put through another amplifier? This is to retrieved the "lost" amplitude of the signal after the tuning is complete. And the reason is to bring the signal into an acceptable range for the ADC. This is all by design.
